# Create a byte array of all zeros except for a specified offset

Tags: python

```
bytearray(0x10)
```

This creates a byte array of all zeros with the length I want, but I want the same byte array except the 3rd b"\x00" is b"\xFF", so it's all zeros except for the third byte. How can I do this as simple and compact as possible?

Comment: Using `variable[3] = 0xff` is not what you want?

Comment: I was just curious if there's a way to pre-generate a byte array like this using a one-liner.

Comment: Not that I know off, but I don't think it's necessary, or even better: setting the specific byte on a separate lines makes it much clearer what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The walrus operator does exactly what you want here, assuming you are going to assign you byte-array to a variable

## Method

```
>>> (my_array := bytearray(0x10))[3] = 0xff
>>> my_array
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

## Why it works?

You can think of the walrus operator as an operator that will assign a thing to a variable and also return the thing. Since we are returning a mutable list, we can modify it on the same line. This would not work for something non-mutable.

In other words we are doing this:

```
>>> (my_array := bytearray(0x10))
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00') 
# see? we get the array as return value. and its mutable so we can modify it.
# so on the same line we can just add the following mutation to the list
>>> my_array[3] = 0xff # returns nothing, this is mutation
```

Below we have an immutable example, a string operation that produces two outputs, one from the replace and one from assingment

```
>>> (foo := "foo").replace("foo","bar") # returns the replace action
'bar'
>>> foo # foo, however, remains unmutated since strings are immutable
'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity, is it possible you can also multiply byte array with the 0xff on the same line by a certain amount so it returns the same byte array but a certain amount of times?

Comment: @JZQAr9kW Yes, but the syntax becomes somewhat strange since you can not chain more walruses after the assingment. You could stack them before. Try (arr := bytearray(0x10))[3] = 0xff; arr = (lambda x,n: x*n)(arr,5). I hope you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @JZQAr9kW You could also approach the problem differently and forego using byte-array call to create empty array. bytearray(b"\x00"*2 + b"\xff" + b"\x00"*7)*10 produces the same result.